# Для чего два разных нуля 0 и -0

Tags: javascript

Зачем в javascript есть два разных нуля.
Я имею ввиду 0 и -0.
У них вообще есть различия? Где это использовать? Потому что `0 === -0 // true`

Comment: Тут об этом подробно описано - [ссылка](https://bolknote.ru/all/3116/) (с ссылками на другие источники и примеры)

Comment: И в интернетах конечно же никто никогда с таким не сталкивался?